# Designing a circuit for active low input relay

Tags: relay

How do i modify the following circuit for a  1 form A contact relay such that it has active low input.[image]

Comment: And second question, your circuit looks like it has been copy-pasted from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html). The same blog has numerous examples of inverse logic. Why don't you use any one of those instead of asking how to modify this one?

Comment: I want the input to be active low such that when output from gpio pin is between 0-0.6V it should turn on and when output is  between 2.7-3.7V it should turn off

Comment: Sorry, I've missed "form A" part of your question. So, you do not have NC contact pair. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZFvlZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could add an NPN and resistor like this.  It will invert the behavior.  The output will be high if the input is low, and vice versa.

Comment: Together with original circuit it would be **way too many** components for such a simple task.

Comment: @Maple: Agreed, however, in a comment on another answer OP expressed interest in adding an NPN to invert the incoming signal.  I don't know why OP cannot simply swap NO and NC.

Comment: OP did not answer my comment on the post yet. One of the obvious reasons could be that input stays high most of the time and OP wants to save power. Regardless of the reason, 2 transistors and 5 resistors is way too much. You can do better.

Comment: Good point.  I also noticed he says it is a form A relay, so there may not be a NC contact in the first place.  Switching to a PNP and using high-side switching would be a much cleaner solution...or are you hinting that I might be able to simplify this approach?

Comment: I am saying that having 1k pull-up on the output connected to 10k pull-down on the input hurts my eyes. Just draw combined schematics and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying.  Does my edit make it better?  This should only be adding 1 transistor and one resistor to his circuit.

Comment: Yes, 1 transistor and 1 resistor is enough. Could be even simpler with PNP. But I don't see any changes. CircuitLab shows the same schematics. Try drawing complete circuit, from input to relay.

Comment: Now I see it. Yep, that should work.

Comment: @Maple Can you show the design of the circuit using a single PNP transistor?

Comment: It is in [the link I mentioned earlier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html). Surprisingly called "PNP Relay Switch Circuit"

Answer (score 0):

Swap the NO and NC connections on the relay.

You can also invert the input signal but that requires an extra transistor.

Comment: With the first option be aware that the circuit will fail 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options:
1) Invert the incoming signal with another NPN transistor.
2) Drive the relay „high side“ with a PNP transistor (instead of low side with NPN)
3) Swap No/Nc of the relay
...